# Change page number color on some chapter pages only

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I'm trying to insert a number of colored pages in my document, and I would like to change the color of the page number on those pages. I'm using fancyhdr to try to change the text color, but it does not work on chapter pages. Any suggestions on how to that without changing the color of page numbers on all other chapter pages as well?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,afterpage,pagecolor,xcolor}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhf{}
\newpagecolor{gray}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\textcolor{red}{\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Here's a chapter}Here the page number should remain black.
\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Here's another chapter}}\pagestyle{style1}
\textcolor{red}{Here I would like the page number to be red.}
\newpage\pagestyle{style1} \textcolor{red}{Here the page number is red (which it should be)!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\thispagestyle{style1}`: `\chapter*{\textcolor{red}{Here's another chapter}}\thispagestyle{style1}`

Comment: Well, that was easy! Thanks!